# Rails nested form attributes not getting saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've already looked through every other stackoverflow for this issue, but none of the solutions have fixed this. My elements in a nested_form are not being saved in the database. I've also made sure that all model associations are correct. I've been trying to fix this for nearly 8 hours now, and would really appreciate some help, especially considering every other solution hasn't worked.

Basically, I have a Playlist model that contains multiple Song models. I'm trying to use a nested_form to add the Song models to the Playlist. However, none of the Songs are ever being saved. I apologize if my methods are misguides, as I'm still fairly new to Rails.

**GitHub Repo:https://github.com/nsalesky/Ultra-Music**

**playlists_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @playlists = @user.playlists
end

def show
    @user = current_user
    @playlist = @user.playlists.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @playlist = Playlist.new

    #I was told to do this
    @playlist.songs.build
end

def create
    @user = current_user
    @playlist = @user.playlists.create(playlist_params)

    if @playlist.save
        redirect_to @playlist
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @playlist = current_user.playlists.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = current_user
    @playlist = @user.playlists.find(params[:id])

    if @playlist.update_attributes(playlist_params)
        redirect_to @playlist
    else
        render :action => 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @playlist = @user.playlists.find(params[:id])
    @playlist.destroy
    redirect_to playlists_path(@user.playlists)
end

private
    def playlist_params
        params.require(:playlist).permit(:name, :description, songs_attributes: [:id, :name, :link, :_destroy])
    end
```

**playlist.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }


  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_associated :songs, presence: true
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @playlist do |f| %>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>

    <!--<div>
        <button type="button" id="addsong">Add Song</button><br>
        <button type="button" id="removesong">Remove Song</button><br>
    </div> !-->

    <div>
        <%= f.fields_for :songs do |song_form| %>
            <%= song_form.text_field :name %>
            <%= song_form.text_field :link %>
            <%= song_form.link_to_remove "Remove Song" %>
        <% end %>
        <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Song", :songs %></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you checked the server's log  when submitting a song on playlist's form page? It might give you some hint. Or you can paste your git repo then I can try help more.

Comment: Here's the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/nsalesky/Ultra-Music

Answer (score 1):

In your playlist.rb, you wrote:

`:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }`

Here the block parameter `|a|` stands for attributes of a specific song. So `a[:attribute]` relates to a single attribute. The problem is your `Song` doesn't have a `:content` attribute. So this `a[:content].blank?` will always be `true`, means you would be rejected building a song.

Just change `a[:content]` to a valid attribute such as `a[:name]`